# how to centre individual sections of a webpage

Tags: center, html

I'm working on a website that's split in three. I have images in the absolute centre and text to the left and right. How would i centre each individual section so its proportionally centred when the webpage alters in width? something involving margin-left/right auto?

Hope that all makes sense..

thanks!

textual diagram

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

stretched webpage

| * * 1 * * | * * 2 * * | * * 3 * * |

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: To clarify, have objects in each 33%-width column that are smaller than the column width, and they must be centered within that column, correcT?

Comment: Jack, I tried playing with width and margin auto.. and searched for an adjustable table which I could have as three columns.. Quite inexperienced in Web Design to be honest, just looking for an initial guide in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the width of the contents of each column ahead of time, you could use 3 scaling divs to represent the columns, each including a fixed-width centered div for the content.

In the body, for the three columns, you could have (replacing pixel widths with sizes appropriate to your page):

```
    <div class="outer" style="margin-left:0; margin-right:67%;">
    <div class="inner" style="width: 100px;">
    <p>some text</p><p>more text</p></div></div>

    <div class="outer" style="margin-left:33%; margin-right:33%;">
    <div class="inner" style="width: 200px;">
    <img src="someimage"></div></div>

    <div class="outer" style="margin-left:67%; margin-right:0;">
    <div class="inner" style="width: 150px;">
    <p>and another<br>piece of text</p></div></div>
```

And, in the head, styles for the divs of each type.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .outer {
    position:absolute;
    width:33%;
    }
    .inner {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
    </style>
```

Depending on the needs of your site, for each inner div, you could set an absolute size, set a relative size (as a percent of the containing 33% width div), or set an absolute left-margin and right-margin width.